# WLAN HTTP connection does not work on Eduroam

Tags: wireless-networking

I am having an app where a local server is set up and others in the same network can connect via HTTP to my IP. 
It worked well on several networks but does not work in [Eduroam](https://www.eduroam.org/) (unable to connect). Both the server and the client I am testing have the same TCP gateway. Any idea what might be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many public-access Wi-Fi networks are configured for "client isolation". That is, to block wireless clients from directly talking to each other, in an attempt to thwart malware and hacker attacks.

It could be that the Eduroam network at your institution is configured that way.

Comment: That's probably the keyword I was looking for, thanks.

If anyone stumbles upon this in the future, here's some details I found:
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/wireless-client-isolation-how-does-it-work-and-can-it-be-bypassed